# Write Bitbucket Pipeline Deployment variables into a file

Tags: variables, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am working on a Deployment with Bitbucket and got some trouble using the variables. In Bitbucket I set in

Repository Settings / Deployment / Staging:

```
SOME_VAR = foobar
```

The bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like this:

```
...
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-some-project
      name: 'Build Project'
      script:
        - echo "\$test='$SOME_VAR';" >> file.php
...
```

I am not able to pass the value of a variable into the file within the `script` part via echo, but why? I also put it in double qutes (like `echo "\$test='"$SOME_VAR"';"`). But the result always is just `$test='';` = an empty string. The expected result should be `$test='foobar';`. Does anybody know how to get this working? The variable is not a secure variable.

// edit
The Repository Variables are working as well. But: I need the same variable with different values for each environment. Also the Repository Variables are accessable for users with permissions to push into the repo.

Answer (score 3):

For the script to understand that the variable to be fetched from the deployment variable mention the deployment type

```yaml
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-some-project
      name: 'Build Project'
      deployment: Staging
      script:
        - echo "\$test='$SOME_VAR';" >> file.php
```